# Execute SQL Query in a controller (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to execute some SQL query from my controller action that takes in the VALES () Parameters based on ids in the view, some code to better explain:

My Controller, based on what i found online :

```
    public ActionResult Add(int id)
    {

        Entitiesdb db = new Entitiesdb();//not sure if this be deck or cards? 
        string query = $"INSERT INTO DeckCards (Card_Id, Deck_id) Values ({cardId},{deckId});";
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, @id);

        return View("Index");
    }
```

My View button that calls the Add Method in the controller:

```
@foreach (var d in Model.Decks)
{
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @Html.ActionLink($"Add to: {d.Name} ", "Add", new { cardId = Model.Cards.Id, deckId = d.id })
</ul>
}
```

My models:

```
 public class Deck
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Card")]
        public virtual List<Card> Card { get; set; }
    }

public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Atk { get; set; }
    public int? Def { get; set; }
    public string Desc {get; set;}
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Image")]
    public virtual List<Image> Card_Images { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Deck> Deck { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: So what's the error!

Comment: Why don't you use the **Entity Framework** capabilities - seeing that you've already referenced it? Create an object of type `DeckCards`, set its properties, then save it using the EF `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method....... what's the point of having EF included, and then using "raw" SQL to do stuff?!?!

Comment: haha sorry! 'Cannot resolve symbol EntitiesDB. I am not sure to what this is referring to, found this on a stack overflow post and it wasnt explained

Comment: @marc_s, i'm very new at entity and not very sure of how to approach what you are recommending, could you provide a snippet to help me understand?

Comment: @also its worth mentioning that there isnt a DeckCard Model, this is a relationship formed in my DB two seperate Deck and Card models. Im confused at to what ntitiesdb db = new Entitiesdb(); refers to in the snippet i sent over

Comment: @Andy EntitiesDB is a Data context class which created while you generate Entity model. Class name are different by case to case. In your case it may  EntitiesDB.

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper ahh i see, so i should have a model called DeckCards and then in this case it will DeckCardsdb = new DeckCardsdb?();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your scenario I assume that you may at least have 3 table.

```
1).Card
2).Desk
3).DeckCard
```

So In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Add(int cardId,int deckId)
{
    using (YourSolution.YoueProjectName.Models.EntitiesDB db=new EntitiesDB())
    {
     DeskCard d=new DeskCard();
     d.Card_Id=cardId;
     d.Deck_Id=deckId;    
     db.DeckCard.Add(d)//Or AddObject() basesd on version
     db.SaveChanges();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: You are indeed correct, I have 3 Tables, but only 2 models (Deck, Card) but not a DeckCard Model. Looks like I will need to create one?

Comment: in INSERT INTO DeckCards (Card_Id, Deck_id) Values ({cardId},{deckId});  what is DeckCards ??

Comment: DeckCards is a table created via the relationship between my two models, look at my edit for info on the two models

Comment: So it's two models referring to the same DB table?

Comment: yeah, that table was auto created by entity framework after i migrated Card and Deck

Comment: oh yes obviously it's the intermediate table because card and deck have many-to-many relationship. In this case, _EntitiesDb_ refers to the two models. The variable _db_ will have the two properties _db.Cards_ and _db.Decks_ which allow you to select, modify and delete data. I strongly recommend you to understand the concepts of EF https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/